# Android Service not running in background?

Tags: android, android-service

The service runs when I press home button or back button but the service is not running in background when app is closed. Moreover the service runs in background in some(LG Nexus 5) phones, but in most of the phones(Samsung,Xioami) service is not running when app is closed. When i goto Settings > Apps > Running, It always shows as app running and displays 1 service 1 thread. I am calling the service from MainActivity.java

I want the service always running in background even if the app is closed. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is code for service TimeService.java

```
public class TimeService extends Service implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL =  30 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

 @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Send message in background

               sendSMS(number,msg)

                               }
                         });
                 }
             }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button btnIn;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIn);

    btnIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        boolean enable = true;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeService.class);
                   startService(intent);
}
}
}
```

Android manifest

```
<service android:name=".TimeService" />
```

Comment: What does the "app is closed" mean? Press back key or kill the process?

Comment: kill the process ie. remove from multitasking

Comment: How do you know the service is not running?

Comment: because it is not sending sms when its closed, but when app is running it sends sms.

Comment: It seems the service is not started automatically when the process is killed.  How about overriding `onStartCommand`?

Comment: Try putting the service in another process like `<service android:name=".TimeService"  android:process="process_name"/>`

Comment: Not working.. Do u think it maybe caused by timer service? Should i user alarm service instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the background task in a separate thread, while it should be in the main thread, that was the reason app was not running in background in some Phones.

```
class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
@Override
public void run() {       
            // Send message in background
           sendSMS(number,msg);
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreground service if you want keep alive your service.

To make it you must run the service in foreground

```
private void runForeground(){
//... Pending intent if you want attach it to the notification


Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.string))
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

}

NOTIFICATION_ID is a number for identify it, return sticky the service.

Comment: Where should i call this?

Comment: You should call it in onCreate

Comment: I didn't want the app to show notification while running, so i didn't use this code.. Thx anyways

Comment: I'm sorry but to run service as forground service (that it's the only way to keep alive your service because Android stop normal service after some times (or memory request) as you can see) notification is mandatory

Comment: Yes android stops normal service after some time, but we can return START_STICKY in onStartCommand so that service restarts when it is stopped.