# Started Service stop listening location updates after application terminates #android

Tags: android

```
In Main Activity:
public void startService(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyServ.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

MyServ.java:

```
public class MyServ extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private long INTERVAL = 500, FASTEST_INTERVAL = 100;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("vats", "In Service : onCreate()");
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listenToLocation();
            }
        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void listenToLocation() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                        Log.d("vats", "In Service :connected...");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.d("vats", "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
                    }
                })
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("vats", "location updates: " + location.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MyServ.this, "location changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("vats","onDestroy()");
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
   }
}
```

No log or toast appear after app terminate (clear from recent list or by back button). Why started service not working after its activity close? Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661165/android-service-not-running-in-background

Comment: Thanks for the response Jas but i dont want to run a foreground service. Any other way ?

Comment: when googleApiClient is connected: onConnected(Bundle bundle) {..

Comment: Your code seems right. You should wait few secs for service to be restarted! Check for this `Log.d("vats", "In Service : onCreate()");` in your log.

Comment: It prints nothing after app terminate but when app is not close then it works fine and send updates after few seconds

Comment: even onDestroy() is not call as its log is not printed on log screen.

Comment: When you clear from Recent list, services and activities are closed in background... But when you are pressing back button, this should not happen with services

Comment: actually there is a bug in android 4.4.2 see this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Comment: but is anyone know how whats app service works?, because it works fine on my device.